# How to send versioned transaction from bytes

Tags: signature, python, transaction, versionedtransactions, magiceden

I am using Magic Eden's API to generate a buy transaction, and it returns the bytes of the transaction. I'm using Python, `solanapy` and `solders` to send the transaction. However I don't know how to interpret the bytes and send them. Here is my code:

```
msg = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(bytes(data[0]))
sig = wallet.sign_message(bytes(msg.message))
msg.verify_and_hash_message()
response = httpClient.send_transaction(
    txn=msg,
    opts=TxOpts(skip_preflight=False, skip_confirmation=True),
)
```

Where `data[0]` is the list of bytes that is returned by Magic Eden. This code gives me the error:

```
msg.verify_and_hash_message()
solders.TransactionError: Transaction did not pass signature verification
```

If I remove the verify, it compiles but the signature is `1111.....111`. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I now have this, which seems to be very close to the actual solution however I'm getting this error
New code:

```
raw_tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(bytes(data[0]))
signature = wallet.sign_message(to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))
signed_tx = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])

txid = httpClient.send_transaction(
    signed_tx,
    opts=TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False, skip_preflight=False),
).value
```

Error when sending transaction:

```
solana.rpc.core.RPCNoResultException: invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly
```

Comment: You don't have to show the full thing, but can you include the link to the magic eden function that gives `data` as its result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
raw_tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(bytes(data))
signature = wallet.sign_message(to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))
signed_tx = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature ,raw_tx.signatures[1]])
```

The data is the signed message from Magic Eden. You have to turn the list into a list of bytes. Then you sign the message and get the signature. Create a new versioned transaction with the message and the signatures from Magic Eden and yours.

And then you can send it using `client.send_transaction(...)`.